# Handling property dependencies

Tags: c#, class, properties

When developing a class (in C# but I suppose this question is somewhat language independent) what is the correct way to deal with dependencies between properties?

For example where I want to create a property B whose value is derived in some way from the value of property A. Property B is undefined and should not be called if property A has not been set. Throwing an exception in B's getter if A has not been set hardly seems like an elegant way of handling this. Simply returning some default value from property B is not something I want to do.

One way is to enforce initialization of A through the constructor, but let's assume that a default constructor with no arguments is required so this is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throwing an `InvalidOperationException` in this case seems entirely proper to me:

> `InvalidOperationException` is used in
>   cases when the failure to invoke a
>   method is caused by reasons other than
>   invalid arguments

Now granted it talks about a *method* rather than a property, but I think it's still fine.

If you want an example from the framework, `IEnumerator.Current` is specified to throw `InvalidOperationException` if it's called before the first element or after the last one. (C#-generated iterators don't do that in fact, but that's a different matter :)

It sounds like it's a *bug* in the calling code to do this... they're using the object improperly. The correct way to indicate a bug is to throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I'll do that then, but it will be interesting to hear of any other options people may have taken.